# java "Class file contains wrong class" error

Tags: java, web-services, classpath, webservice-client, wsimport

I'm trying to make a console application to test my webservice.
I successfully deployed a webservice at http://localhost:8080/WS/myWS
and i made proxy classes with wsimport:

```
wsimport -d bin -s src http://localhost:8080/WS/myWS?wsdl
```

Now my webservice classes are located in bin/mywebservice/ and i'm trying to compile my client class with classpath = ./

Here's the source code of my class:

```
import bin.mywebservice.myClass_Service;
public class TesterApp{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {    
        myClass_Service service = new myClass_Service(); 
    }
}
```

And i have error:

```
TesterApp.java:1: error: cannot access myClass_Service
import bin.mywebservice_Service.myClass;
                               ^
  bad class file: .\bin\mywebservice\myClass_Service.class
    class file contains wrong class: mywebservice.myClass_Service
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

please help, what's wrong with myClass_Service?
i swear, myClass_Service.class exists in .\bin\mywebservice\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're incorrectly including the `bin` in the `import` declaration.

Rather put `bin` on the classpath and correct the `import`.

Unless (the poorly-named) `myClass_Service.java` file is `package bin.mywebservice` (which it isn't, according the the error message), you're trying to correct the problem in the wrong place.

Comment: shame on me. i should start learning java from the very beginning.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the generated class has a package `mywebservice`, not `bin.mywebservice`.  Make sure the `bin` directory is on the classpath, and drop `bin` from the packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that your file located in `bin` directory, you have check the class file that for call `mywebservice.myClass_Service`

same at the `bin` directory. because when both file not the same location, it will be error. or you can check your package location on the top of code.

> package bin;

look and compare the two.

Answer (score -1):

This makefile may help if you are using packages:

```
CLASS_PATH = ../bin

vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)

all : HelloJNI.h

HelloJNI.h : com/my/package/HelloJNI.class
    javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) com.my.package.$*
```