# using package which need modification, class file contains wrong class

Tags: java

i have java programm which use package "jahuwaldt" and which I have to change a class Inside, I take the source code, i made  modification, i compile then and I added class to the packag, but i have this error

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_01\bin>javac HT_plane_FD_T.java    
HT_plane_FD_T.java:389: cannot access ContourPlot    
bad class file: .\ContourPlot.class    
class file contains wrong class: jahuwaldt.plot.ContourPlot    
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.    
ContourPlot pp=new ContourPlot(a,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,40, false,"x","y","T=f(x,y)");    
^   
1 error
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377239/java-class-file-contains-wrong-class-error), your error is that you are providing the wrong path for your `ContourPlot.class` file.

Are you sure the file is in that directory?

Comment: Ok. And what is the value of the `package` declaration within the file?

Comment: like this package jahuwaldt.plot;

Comment: Well then your file should be placed in `.\jahuwald\plot\ContourPlot.class` and not `.\ContourPlot.class`.

Comment: here's my problem: class HT_plane_FD_T in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_01\bin use package "jahuwaldt" and use class Plot3D in the same classpath whene i put >>package jahuwaldt.plot; in HT_plane_FD_T class i have error >> cannot find symbol Plot3D

Comment: and whene i remove package jahuwaldt.plot i get error mentioned above